# How to embed inmutable dataset in a web page?

Tags: javascript, json, web, storage

First of anything, sorry for any grammar error, I have a **very very bad** english, any correction is appreciated.

## The question

I want to know how to store and embed a small **inmutable** dataset in a web page, is a json file adecuate?, is a database overkill?

Thanks in advance.

## What I'm trying to do

I'm want to make a small web page to create pokemon teams, only using pokemon of the original games (1st generation), that's way the data is inmutable.

Comment: Anything you send from your server to your client may be modified freely; you lose control.